# boxplot in ggplot for two groups of data in the same data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to make a boxplot in ggplot for two groups of data in the same data frame. One would be for all years below a certain number and the other for all years above. I have tried sub-setting the data, pipes with filter and group by but nothing works and I am new to R. I feel like there should be a simple answer to this. My data frame has three columns: ID, Year and Amount.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a group with comparison operator

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
   mutate(year_grp = case_when(year < 1969 ~ "below 1969", TRUE ~ ">= 1969")) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = year_grp, y = anflow)) + 
     geom_boxplot()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = 1:31, year = 1950:1980, anflow = c(4910L, 
3660L, 3910L, 1750L, 1050L, 2670L, 2880L, 2600L, 3520L, 1730L, 
2340L, 2600L, 3410L, 1870L, 1730L, 2730L, 1550L, 4060L, 2870L, 
1350L, 2350L, 3140L, 3060L, 3630L, 3890L, 3870L, 3180L, 2260L, 
3430L, 5290L, 2870L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"))
```